# Error parsing HTTP request header Tomcat 7

Tags: java, tomcat

When it stops working, I am getting this error:

```
mai 06, 2015 12:47:58 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor process
INFO: Error parsing HTTP request header
 Note: further occurrences of HTTP header parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.
```

All others errors after this, is just the same. I have tried to stop the get-requests, but it crashes after a while anyways. Do you have any ideas?

This is right before it crashes:

```
  [06/May/2015:10:47:11 +0200] "GET /ListenerServlet?request=getLastChanged&_=1430852558104 HTTP/1.1" 200 32
```

After the crash:

```
    [06/May/2015:10:47:14 +0200] "GET /ListenerServlet?request=getLastChanged&_=1430902035081 HTTP/1.1" 500 1674
```

After the crash, the Servlet can't get the request parameter.. that throws this nullpointer:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [RoomServlet] in context with path [] threw exception java.lang.NullPointerException
        at factory.Factory.initEditMode(Factory.java:37)
        at factory.Factory.init(Factory.java:20)
        at factory.TabsFactory.<init>(TabsFactory.java:19)
        at servlet.RoomServlet.getTabs(RoomServlet.java:285)
        at servlet.RoomServlet.doGet(RoomServlet.java:46)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I have a Tomcat 7 server that receives a lot of GET-requests. This works very well for some time, then suddenly it stops working (after 7-8 hours).

When it stops working, I am getting this error:

```
mai 06, 2015 12:47:58 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor process
INFO: Error parsing HTTP request header
 Note: further occurrences of HTTP header parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.
```

All others errors after this, is just the same. I have tried to stop the get-requests, but it crashes after a while anyways. Do you have any ideas?

This is right before it crashes:

```
[06/May/2015:10:47:11 +0200] "GET /ListenerServlet?request=getLastChanged&_=1430852558104 HTTP/1.1" 200 32
```

After the crash:

```
[06/May/2015:10:47:14 +0200] "GET /ListenerServlet?request=getLastChanged&_=1430902035081 HTTP/1.1" 500 1674
```

After the crash, the Servlet can't get the request parameter.. that throws this nullpointer:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [RoomServlet] in context with path [] threw exception java.lang.NullPointerException
        at factory.Factory.initEditMode(Factory.java:37)
        at factory.Factory.init(Factory.java:20)
        at factory.TabsFactory.<init>(TabsFactory.java:19)
        at servlet.RoomServlet.getTabs(RoomServlet.java:285)
        at servlet.RoomServlet.doGet(RoomServlet.java:46)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

followed by:

```
mai 07, 2015 9:58:00 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStop
SEVERE: Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class websocket.drawboard.DrawboardContextListener
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/websocket/Endpoint
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2944)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1208)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1688)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1569)
        at websocket.drawboard.DrawboardContextListener.contextDestroyed(DrawboardContextListener.java:32)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:5014)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5659)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1564)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.websocket.Endpoint
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1718)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1569)
        ... 17 more
```

Comment: what JVM parameters (xmx, xms, min and maxpermgensize) are you using? on what operating system and under what jre/jdk is this server running?

Comment: Are you using Websockets ?
Can you paste your server.xml

Comment: I also agree with Marcelo , it must be memory issue you must increase your maximum size by -Xmx